# Cycle through images until hover jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want the images to cycle through individually, say change image every 2 seconds, but then switch to the correct image when the associated link is hovered. The following is what I have managed to get so far. Right now, I got the images to show on hover, but I am not sure how to get them to cycle.

```
$("#one").on({
mouseover: function () {
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
        $("#first").removeClass('hidden').css('opacity', '1');
    }, 300);
},
mouseout: function () {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    $("#first").css({
        'opacity': '0'
    }).addClass('hidden');
}
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/enwed7b9/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some broken image link in your HTML. But this should do the trick:
https://jsfiddle.net/pengyanb/st47yxqb/6/

```js
var imageIndex = 0;
var periodicTimer;
setPeriodicTimer();

function setPeriodicTimer()
{
    periodicTimer = setTimeout(function(){
        $('img').addClass('hidden').css('opacity', '0');
        console.log('imageIndex: '+imageIndex);
  switch(imageIndex)
        {
            case 0:
                $('#first').removeClass('hidden').css('opacity', '1');
                break;
           case 1:
                $('#second').removeClass('hidden').css('opacity', '1');
                break;
           case 2:
                $('#third').removeClass('hidden').css('opacity', '1');
                break;       
           case 3:
                $('#fourth').removeClass('hidden').css('opacity', '1');
                break;
   
           case 4:
                $('#fifth').removeClass('hidden').css('opacity', '1');
                break;
           case 5:
                $('#sixth').removeClass('hidden').css('opacity', '1');
                break;
           case 6:
                $('#seventh').removeClass('hidden').css('opacity', '1');
                break;
        }
        imageIndex++;
        if(imageIndex > 6)
            imageIndex = 0;
        setPeriodicTimer();
 }, 2000);
}

$("#one").on({
    mouseover: function () {
        clearTimeout(periodicTimer);
        imageIndex = 0;
        $('img').addClass('hidden').css('opacity', '0');
        timer = setTimeout(function () {
            $("#first").removeClass('hidden').css('opacity', '1');
        }, 300);
    },
    mouseout: function () {
        setPeriodicTimer();
        clearTimeout(timer);
        $("#first").css({
            'opacity': '0'
        }).addClass('hidden');
    }
});
$("#two").on({
    mouseover: function () {
        clearTimeout(periodicTimer);
        imageIndex = 1;
        $('img').addClass('hidden').css('opacity', '0');
        timer = setTimeout(function () {
            $("#second").removeClass('hidden').css('opacity', '1');
        }, 300);
    },
    mouseout: function () {
        setPeriodicTimer();
        clearTimeout(timer);
        $("#second").css({
            'opacity': '0'
        }).addClass('hidden');
    }
});
$("#three").on({
    mouseover: function () {
        clearTimeout(periodicTimer);
        imageIndex = 2;
        $('img').addClass('hidden').css('opacity', '0');
        timer = setTimeout(function () {
            $("#third").removeClass('hidden').css('opacity', '1');
        }, 300);
    },
    mouseout: function () {
        setPeriodicTimer();
        clearTimeout(timer);
        $("#third").css({
            'opacity': '0'
        }).addClass('hidden');
    }
});
$("#four").on({
    mouseover: function () {
        clearTimeout(periodicTimer);
        imageIndex = 3;
        $('img').addClass('hidden').css('opacity', '0');
        timer = setTimeout(function () {
            $("#fourth").removeClass('hidden').css('opacity', '1');
        }, 300);
    },
    mouseout: function () {
        setPeriodicTimer();
        clearTimeout(timer);
        $("#fourth").css({
            'opacity': '0'
        }).addClass('hidden');
    }
});
$("#five").on({
    mouseover: function () {
        clearTimeout(periodicTimer);
        imageIndex = 4;
        $('img').addClass('hidden').css('opacity', '0');
        timer = setTimeout(function () {
            $("#fifth").removeClass('hidden').css('opacity', '1');
        }, 300);
    },
    mouseout: function () {
        setPeriodicTimer();
        clearTimeout(timer);
        
        $("#fifth").css({
            'opacity': '0'
        }).addClass('hidden');
    }
});
$("#six").on({
    mouseover: function () {
        clearTimeout(periodicTimer);
        imageIndex = 5;
        $('img').addClass('hidden').css('opacity', '0');
        timer = setTimeout(function () {
            $("#sixth").removeClass('hidden').css('opacity', '1');
        }, 300);
    },
    mouseout: function () {
        setPeriodicTimer();
        clearTimeout(timer);
        $("#sixth").css({
            'opacity': '0'
        }).addClass('hidden');
    }
});
$("#seven").on({
    mouseover: function () {
        clearTimeout(periodicTimer);
        imageIndex = 6;
        $('img').addClass('hidden').css('opacity', '0');
        timer = setTimeout(function () {
            $("#seventh").removeClass('hidden').css('opacity', '1');
        }, 300);
    },
    mouseout: function () {
        setPeriodicTimer();
        clearTimeout(timer);
        $("#seventh").css({
            'opacity': '0'
        }).addClass('hidden');
    }
});
```

```css
.box {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 15px;
    line-height: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    transition: .3s;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    margin-right: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 7px
}

.image {
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1
}
.image img {
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 10%;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 55%;
    transition: ease-out .4s;
    z-index: -1
}
.hidden {
   
    opacity: 1
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="project-link-2">
    <li class="box" id="one"> <a class="project-link" href="#modal1"><span>Modurra Shelving</span>   </a> 
    </li>
    <br>
    <li class="box" id="two"> <a class="project-link" href="#modal2"><span>Kami Bicycle Helmet</span> </a> 
    </li>
    <br>
    <li class="box" id="three"> <a class="project-link" href="#modal3"><span>Revamping Language Learning</span> </a> 
    </li>
    <br>
    <li class="box" id="four"> <a class="project-link" href="#modal4"><span>Sports Innovation Challenge</span> </a> 
    </li>
    <br>
    <li class="box" id="five"> <a class="project-link" href="#modal5"><span>Lights Out</span></a> 
    </li>
    <br>
    <li class="box" id="six"> <a class="project-link" href="#modal6"><span>Maru Personal Speaker Design</span> </a> 
    </li>
    <br>
    <li class="box" id="seven"> <a class="project-link" href="#modal7"><span>A Few Casual Projects</span> </a> 
    </li>
</ul>
   
        
        
<div class="image">
    <img alt="" class="hidden" id="first" src="http://consequenceofsound.files.wordpress.com/2013/06/datside-ram.jpg">
</div>
<!-- Lights Out -->
<div class="image">
    <img alt="" class="hidden" id="second" src="http://tctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com/2012/03/random_house_logo.jpg">
</div>
<!-- Modurra -->
<div class="image">
    <img alt="" class="hidden" id="third" src="work/Wordpix/splash_word.jpg">
</div>
<!-- WordPix -->
<div class="image">
    <img alt="" class="hidden" id="fourth" src="work/Sports/splash_sports.jpg">
</div>
<!-- Luna -->
<div class="image">
    <img alt="" class="hidden" id="fifth" src="work/Lights Out/Lights-Out-Gif.gif">
</div>
<!-- Kami -->
<div class="image">
    <img alt="" class="hidden" id="sixth" src="work/Maru/splash_maru.jpg">
</div>
<!-- Misc -->
<div class="image">
    <img alt="" class="hidden" id="seventh" src="work/Misc/splash_comp.jpg">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome. A quick comment though. How do you get the images to not load all at the same time? Some are of different sizes, so you can see them all be stacked up on top of each other until they finish the first cycle.

Comment: Do you want to hide all the images when page load initially? If so, you can simply add this line:  $('img').addClass('hidden').css('opacity', '0'); at beginning to hide all img by default.  https://jsfiddle.net/pengyanb/st47yxqb/7/

Comment: Ahhh I see. Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 1):

This will cycle to the next image every 3 seconds, and will stop cycling and show the hovered image when the user hovers over the link.

```
var autoCycle = true;
var i = 1;
var images = [
    $('#first'),
    $('#second'),
    $('#third'),
    $('#fourth'),
    $('#fifth'),
    $('#sixth'),
    $('#seventh')
];

images[0].removeClass('hidden').css('opacity', '1');

setInterval(function() {
    if(autoCycle) {
        images.forEach(function(img) {
            img.css({ 'opacity': '0' }).addClass('hidden');
        });

        var currImage = images[(i - 1) % images.length];
        var newImage = images[i % images.length];

        currImage.css({ 'opacity': '0' }).addClass('hidden');
        newImage.removeClass('hidden').css('opacity', '1');

        i++;
    }
}, 200);
```

Then you will need to update your calls to on() to set autoCycle to true or false when the user hovers or stops hovering over links:

```
$("#one").on({
    mouseover: function () {
        autoCycle = false;
        timer = setTimeout(function () {
            $("#first").removeClass('hidden').css('opacity', '1');
        }, 300);
    },
    mouseout: function () {
        autoCycle = true;
        clearTimeout(timer);
        $("#first").css({
            'opacity': '0'
        }).addClass('hidden');
    }
});
```

Comment: I also updated your code to be a little more DRY and avoid repetitive code. Here is a fiddle for it: https://jsfiddle.net/enwed7b9/8/

Comment: Awesome. A quick comment though. How do you get the images to not load all at the same time? Some are of different sizes, so you can see them all be stacked up on top of each other until they finish the first cycle.

Answer (score 0):

This should be generic as possible,

You should try to reduce code repeat as long as possible.
You can create a general functionality with a link to images in the following matter:

HTML: (removed ID's from links, added "data-id" --> this is the 'link' to the image)

```
<ul class="project-link-2">
    <li class="box" data-id="first"> <a class="project-link" href="#modal1"><span>Modurra Shelving</span>   </a>    
    </li>
    <br>
    <li class="box" data-id="second"> <a class="project-link" href="#modal2"><span>Kami Bicycle Helmet</span> </a>  
    </li>
    <br>
    <li class="box" data-id="third"> <a class="project-link" href="#modal3"><span>Revamping Language Learning</span> </a>   
    </li>
    <br>
    <li class="box" data-id="fourth"> <a class="project-link" href="#modal4"><span>Sports Innovation Challenge</span> </a>  
    </li>
    <br>
    <li class="box" data-id="fifth"> <a class="project-link" href="#modal5"><span>Lights Out</span></a> 
    </li>
    <br>
    <li class="box" data-id="sixth"> <a class="project-link" href="#modal6"><span>Maru Personal Speaker Design</span> </a>  
    </li>
    <br>
    <li class="box" data-id="seventh"> <a class="project-link" href="#modal7"><span>A Few Casual Projects</span> </a>   
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="image">
    <img alt="" class="hidden" id="first" src="http://consequenceofsound.files.wordpress.com/2013/06/datside-ram.jpg">
</div>
<!-- Lights Out -->
<div class="image">
    <img alt="" class="hidden" id="second" src="http://tctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com/2012/03/random_house_logo.jpg">
</div>
<!-- Modurra -->
<div class="image">
    <img alt="" class="hidden" id="third" src="http://www.independent.co.uk/incoming/article8465213.ece/alternates/w620/v2-cute-cat-picture.jpg" />
</div>
<!-- WordPix -->
<div class="image">
    <img alt="" class="hidden" id="fourth" src="work/Sports/splash_sports.jpg">
</div>
<!-- Luna -->
<div class="image">
    <img alt="" class="hidden" id="fifth" src="work/Lights Out/Lights-Out-Gif.gif">
</div>
<!-- Kami -->
<div class="image">
    <img alt="" class="hidden" id="sixth" src="work/Maru/splash_maru.jpg">
</div>
<!-- Misc -->
<div class="image">
    <img alt="" class="hidden" id="seventh" src="work/Misc/splash_comp.jpg">
</div>
</div>
```

JS: (removed A LOT of unneeded code)

```
var position = 0 / 1; // (divide by 1 to make sure it is int)
var myImgArr = $(".image img");
var count = myImgArr.length;
var timer;

$(function () {
    //on page load

    //show first pic
    $(myImgArr[0]).removeClass('hidden');
    timer = setInterval(setMySlider, 2000);
});

$(".project-link-2 li").mouseenter(function () {
    //stop the timer, reset all images
    clearInterval(timer);
    myImgArr.addClass('hidden');
    myID = '#' + $(this).attr('data-id');
    $(myID).removeClass('hidden');
}).mouseleave(function () {
    //add these 2 lines to hide the current ID:
    myID = '#' + $(this).attr('data-id');
    $(myID).addClass('hidden');
    //this line will show current img and continue cycle
    $(myImgArr[mod]).removeClass('hidden');
    timer = setInterval(setMySlider, 2000);
});

function setMySlider() {

    mod = ((position % count) / 1); //the current position from 0 to image count

    $(myImgArr[mod]).addClass('hidden');
     position++;
     mod = ((position % count) / 1)
    $(myImgArr[mod]).removeClass('hidden');

}
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/qwbo6n70/8/)

Comment: Ah I see. When you hover though, say the first image, and then mouse off the link. That first image is still there. It just becomes overlayed by the next cycled image. How can I get it to disappear when the cycle continues?

Comment: simply add to hide the current id when you leave. Updated + fiddle